# Problem with updating a blog in Laravel Inertia.js when uploading an image

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm facing an issue with my Laravel Inertia.js code when trying to update my blog. During the update process, when I upload a new image, I receive validation errors for the 'title' and 'content' fields even though they are filled out. However, if I update without uploading an image, everything works fine.

```
// web.php
Route::resource('/blog', BlogController::class);
```

```
// controller

    public function edit (Blog $blog)
    {
        return Inertia::render('Blog/Edit', [
            'blog' => $blog
        ]);
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Blog $blog)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|string|min:3',
            'content' => 'required|min:3',
            'image_path' => 'nullable|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        if ($request->file('image_path')) {
            if ($blog->image_path) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($blog->image_path);
            }
            $imagePath = $request->file('image_path')->store('images/blog', 'public');
        } else {
            $imagePath = $blog->image_path;
        }

        $blog->update([
            'title' => $validated['title'],
            'content' => $validated['content'],
            'image_path' => $imagePath,
        ]);

        return Redirect::route('blog.list')->with(
            'message',
            'Mis à jour avec succès !'
        );
    }
```

```
// model

<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class Blog extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Sluggable;

    protected $fillable = ['title', 'content', 'image_path'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function ($blog) {
            if ($blog->image_path) {
                Storage::disk('public')->delete($blog->image_path);
            }
        });
    }

    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'title'
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

}
```

```
// Edit form 

<template>
    <AuthenticatedLayout>
        <div
            class="min-h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-gray-100 py-12 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8"
        >
            <div
                class="max-w-4xl w-full space-y-8 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-md"
            >
                <div>
                    <h2
                        class="mt-6 text-center text-3xl font-extrabold text-gray-900"
                    >
                        Modifier blog
                    </h2>
                </div>
               <form
                    class="mt-8 space-y-6"
                    @submit.prevent="update"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                >
                    <div class="rounded-md shadow-sm -space-y-px">
                        <div>
                            <label for="title" class="sr-only">Title</label>
                            <input
                                id="title"
                                name="title"
                                type="text"
                                v-model="form.title"
                                required
                                class="appearance-none rounded-none relative block w-full px-3 py-2 border border-gray-300 placeholder-gray-500 text-gray-900 rounded-t-md focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 focus:z-10 sm:text-sm"
                                placeholder="Title"
                            />
                            <InputError
                                :message="form.errors.title"
                                class="my-2"
                            />
                        </div>

                        <div class="mt-4">
                            <label for="content" class="sr-only">Content</label>
                            <QuillEditor
                                v-model:content="form.content"
                                contentType="html"
                                theme="snow"
                                toolbar="full"
                                style="height: 200px"
                                placeholder="Écrivez le contenu ici..."
                                aria-required="false"
                            />
                            <InputError
                                :message="form.errors.content"
                                class="mt-2"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mt-4 flex flex-col">
                        <label for="image_path" class="sr-only">Image</label>
                        <input
                            type="file"
                            @change="uploadImage"
                            class="cursor-pointer"
                        />
                        <InputError
                            :message="form.errors.image_path"
                            class="mt-2"
                        />
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <ButtonPrimary type="submit" class="w-full">
                            Modifier blog
                        </ButtonPrimary>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AuthenticatedLayout>
</template>

<script setup>
import { QuillEditor } from '@vueup/vue-quill'
import '@vueup/vue-quill/dist/vue-quill.snow.css'
import ButtonPrimary from '@/Components/ButtonPrimary.vue'
import { useForm } from '@inertiajs/vue3'
import InputError from '@/Components/InputError.vue'
import AuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/AuthenticatedLayout.vue'

const props = defineProps(['blog'])
const form = useForm({
    title: props.blog.title,
    content: props.blog.content,
    image_path: props.blog.image_path,
})

const uploadImage = (event) => {
    form.image_path = event.target.files[0]
}

const update = () => {
    form.put(route('blog.update', { blog: props.blog.slug }), {
        onSuccess: () => form.reset(),
    })
}
</script>
```

Comment: have you try to debug title and content request? `dd($validated['title'])` or `dd($validated['content'])` if the result give null value, i think there is problem from your front end vue js. it's doesn't send anything value to controller. so the validation will give the return response for empty title or content because of it.

Comment: yes yes I did it, but the dd doesn't work if I upload directly, it displays the error `The title field is required.` & `The content field is required.` Yet my fields are filled. Even if I empty and refill the field, it displays this as long as I've uploaded a new image.

Comment: you can place `dd` above your validation to make sure that your request input is not null

Comment: it loads endlessly and doesn't show me anything